# C# MongoDB.Driver : How to see if server is connected. GetServer Replacement

Tags: c#, mongodb

GetServer is gone for good. How do i check if the server is connected or even exists?

**Example code:**

```
// This server exists
var exists = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.2.109:27017");

// This server does not exist
var doesNotExist = new MongoClient("mongodb://194.168.200.129:27017");

// Both states return "Discennected"
var connStateExisting = exists.Cluster.Description.State;
var connStateNotExisting = doesNotExist.Cluster.Description.State;

// GetDatabase("name") works for both without errors.
```

How can i check if a server can be connected?

Answer (score 0):

The Cluster.Description.State does not update immediately. When i checked, it was updated after roughly 100+ milliseconds. The driver contains a connection pool and it seems to do quite a lot asynchronous.

However, the Cluster-property has a "DescriptionChanged"-event that is fired once the connection is done.

If someone else has any knowledge about connections and timeouts, please share it.